# How can we use importance sampling for drawing posterior distribution samples?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, importance-sampling

Today I read that **Importance Sampling** can be used to draw posterior distribution samples just like **Rejection Sampling**. However, my understanding of **Importance Sampling** is that its main purpose is to just compute expectations (ie. integrals) that would otherwise be hard to compute. How can **Importance Sampling** be used to draw posterior distribution samples from a Bayesian Model?

Comment: Where have you read this?

Comment: A newer duplicate of this question emerged, and I commented the following: "yes, you're describing SIR (sampling importance resampling) aka factored sampling. It was invented in 1987!"